# How can I change the height of the tabs in MaterialTopTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, user-interface, configuration, tabs

Currently the tabs are set at a fixed size, leaving a lot of white space above them.

I'd like to be able to adjust the height of the tabs.

The only height setting I can find in the source code is for the size of the icon.

How can I change the height of the tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1:

```
tabBarStyle= { backgroundColor: 'powderblue', height: <SPECIFY HEIGHT> }
```

I think this should work.

Option 2:

```
tabBarContentContainerStyle= {height: <SPECIFY HEIGHT>}
```

You can pass the style object for the view containing the tab items.

Option 3:

```
tabBar={() => return <></>}
```

You can also pass a completely different element for the tab bar using the param tabBar.

Comment: this worked in that it changed the height of the tab bar, but it doesn't seem to have changed the heights of the buttons: they are just cut off by the shortened height.

Comment: ah, the answer to that is tabBarItemStyle. Excellent. Thank you.

Comment: It sort of works. There's a limit on the adjustability apparently.

Comment: ah, and then you use tabBarLabelStyle to make further adjustments. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass styles to the navigator as displayed in [this example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#example) from their documentation.

```
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: '#e91e63',
        tabBarLabelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
        tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: 'powderblue' },
      }}
```